# Question about generating arrays of arrays of specific length

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Say that I have some array `a = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` and some variable `length`. I'm looking for a way to generate an array consisting of arrays of length `length` with in each array some number in the array `a`. For example, say `length = 3`, then I'm trying to generate the array `b = numpy.array([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5]])`. I had the idea of trying `b = np.full((1,length), a)`, but that doesn't seem to work as expected. Any ideas? For efficiency I'd like to stay with numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with using `repeat` and `reshape`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
length = 3

# repeat each element in a by length and then reshape such that there are 3 columns
b = np.repeat(a, length).reshape(-1, length)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[[1 1 1]
 [2 2 2]
 [3 3 3]
 [4 4 4]
 [5 5 5]]
```

Comment: Or without the reshape: `b = np.repeat(a[:,None], length, axis=1)`

Comment: @LeoE that looks cool solution too!

Comment: That does it! With 3 replaced by length of course for anyone else who needs it.

Comment: Great it worked. Updated the answer. `Happy Coding`.